# Show the image stored in Firebase storage in Imageview from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show the image which has been sucessfully uploaded in firebase storage and whose unique id is also updated in Firebase Database under "pics" in my Imageview but I did tried multiple time but am unable to show the image or retrive images .

Below is my Firebase Database Structure.
[image]

and my Imageview is 
[image]

Where image should be displayed in place of Bookshelf which is default pic but unable to do so.
Below is my upload Activity

```html
public class UploadBook extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    EditText etAuthor, etbookDesc, etbookTitle, etName, etEmail, etMobile, etUniversity, etbookPrice;
    ImageView iv1;
    Button b1;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    String item = "start";  // for spinner
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    StorageReference mStorageRef;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    int count = 0;
    Uri filePath = null;
    public Books b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.layout.activity_upload_book);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Upload book");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UploadBook.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 11);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference();
        fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.itemImage1);

        etAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText1);
        etbookDesc = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText2);
        etbookTitle = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText3);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText4);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText5);
        etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText6);
        etUniversity = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText7);
        etbookPrice = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.buttonPost);

        t3 t = new t3();
        t.execute();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.spinner1);
        final String[] items = new String[]{"Select your category :", "Computer Science", "Electronics", "Mechanical", "Civil", "Electrical", "Mechatronics", "Software", "Others"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
        spinner.setActivated(false);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                count = position;
                if (position == 0)
                    return;
                Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });

        imageButtonclick();
        postButtonClick();

        builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Discard this item !");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder1.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent in = new Intent(UploadBook.this, BooksPage.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    void imageButtonclick() {
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CropImage.activity(filePath).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1).start(UploadBook.this);

                // Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageuri);
                //startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    void postButtonClick() {
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Please select a valid category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(etMobile.getText()) || etMobile.getText().toString().trim().length() != 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Please check number format !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (etAuthor.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && etbookDesc.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && etbookTitle.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && etName.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && etEmail.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && etMobile.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && etUniversity.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && etbookPrice.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && filePath!=null) {
                    String bauthor = etAuthor.getText().toString();
                    String bdesc = etbookDesc.getText().toString();
                    String btitle = etbookTitle.getText().toString();
                    String sellername = etName.getText().toString();
                    String selleremail = etEmail.getText().toString();
                    Long sellermobile = Long.parseLong(etMobile.getText().toString());
                    String selleruniversity = etUniversity.getText().toString();
                    Double bprice = Double.parseDouble(etbookPrice.getText().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your book will be uploaded shortly !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    b = new Books(btitle, bauthor, bdesc, sellername, selleremail, sellermobile, item, selleruniversity, bprice);

                    String bookid = dbreference.child("books").child(item).push().getKey();
                    dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid).setValue(b);

                    t2 t2 = new t2();
                    t2.execute(bookid);

                    Intent in = new Intent(UploadBook.this, BooksPage.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Please enter your complete details !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /*AlertDialog alert2 = builder1.create();
        alert2.show();*/
        CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(UploadBook.this);
        cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        cdd.show();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            iv1.setImageURI(filePath);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                iv1.setImageURI(resultUri);
                filePath = resultUri;

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }

    class t2 extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... bookid) {
            if(filePath != null) {
                mStorageRef.child(bookid[0]).putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
                        Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid[0]).child("pics").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                    }
                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Upload Failed : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class t3 extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            publishProgress();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            etName.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("name","Delault name"));
            etEmail.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("email","Default email"));
            etUniversity.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("university","Default university"));
            etMobile.setText(String.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("phone","Default phone")));
        }
    }
```

and my Adapter class is

```html
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    Books b;

    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView bookName,bookAuthor,bookDesc,bookPrice,bookCall;
        ImageView iv;

        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);

            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("books");
            bookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
            bookAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            bookDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDesc);
            bookPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookPrice);
            bookCall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookCall);
            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("books");

        b = bookslist.get(position);
        holder.bookName.setText(b.getBname());
        holder.bookAuthor.setText(b.getBauthor());
        holder.bookDesc.setText(b.getBdesc());
        holder.bookPrice.setText("Rs. "+b.getPrice());
        holder.bookCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log.e("Current user is ", fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                b = bookslist.get(position);
                String[] arr = {b.getSelleremail(),b.getSellername(),b.getBname(),b.getBauthor()};
                //Log.e("Seller is ",b.getSellername());
                Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(),Chat.class);
                in.putExtra("seller",arr);
                v.getContext().startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        Glide.with(cv.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(b.getPics())).placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.bshelf).into(holder.iv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Here is my whole project 
https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/Pustak

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for the image link in bowser. Is that working @Bir Nepali

Comment: yes raj..I opened storage and clicked on images and from right panel under Download url ..I copied the url and posted in Browser andit works ..here is the link i copied   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-bazaar-fa63c.appspot.com/o/-LLBDOMjxj5GhU9_hnNH?alt=media&token=a5789ad5-d04b-4cba-9c5e-9b76267c8586

Comment: Check `b.getPics()` is returning valid url that you confirmed displays image in browser. Use logcat.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: There is this reponse in logcat FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: Not from storage. But the one you saved in database. i.e. with key - pics. Is that working ?

Comment: @Raj no when I copy and paste on browser url  instead it open google search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UploadBook class change this

```
if(filePath != null) {
    mStorageRef.child(bookid[0]).putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
            Toast.makeText(UploadBook.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid[0]).child("pics").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
     });
}
```

To This-

```
final StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child(bookid[0]);
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();

    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid[0]).child("pics").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
            } else {
                 // Handle failures
            }
       }
});
```

Comment: First delete the old entries from database. And then execute this.

Comment: Thanks raj...I watched over dozen of tutorials and fianally solved myself..but much appreciated your help too..!! Raj can you help me ..How can I delete data particular data from Database ..since it is an book selling apps .when book is sold..user can delete that book. In short..How to delete the database from onclick of Button?

Comment: Use dbref.child("books").child("Computer Science").child(key).removeValue();

Comment: will that change all the list inside the Computer Science group or just one particular  child of Computer Science??

Comment: It will delete only that book, for which u specify the key.